# Are there missing padding options from PHP?

Tags: php, openssl, rsa, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to get my front end and backend communicating with private key pairs, using JS on the front end with https://github.com/vibornoff/asmcrypto.js, and PHP on the backend with php's `openssl` library.

`asmcrypto` has some functions to encrypt like: `asmCrypto.RSA_OAEP_SHA1.encrypt()`. It also has `asmCrypto.RSA_OAEP_SHA256.encrypt()` which I assume is more secure, but PHP only wants to decrypt with the option `OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING`, which only works for `SHA1`, and not `SHA256`.

Also, it seems that `openssl_public_decrypt()` and `openssl_private_encrypt()` are missing the `OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING`, and won't work with that option at all, only `OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING` and `OPENSSL_NO_PADDING`, which I understand are both very insecure.

OpenSSL is kind of the standard tool for a lot of encryption systems, so I can't imaging they are missing from that toolkit. Is it just not implemented in PHP? Is there another library that has these available, without having to use a PHP library that does all the calculation?

Comment: `openssl_private_encrypt` is for signature generation and would need PSS and not OAEP. The `encrypt` in `openssl_private_encrypt` is really misleading in that regard.

Comment: it's my understand that while it is usually used for signing it CAN also be used for encryption in the same way that openssl_public_encrypt can be, with the opposite key unlocking it. i switched to a script based library phpseclib which allows me to do this better, but my concern is going to be performance at some point.

Comment: Technically, in textbook RSA, both operations work in exactly the same way just with different exponents. Remember that private key encryption is useless if anybody knows the public key which can be used to decrypt the ciphertext. That's why this direction is used for signature generation.